# CSS syntax for link formatting

Tags: css, syntax, minify

The following code looks inefficient to me.  Is there a way to list all these properties without writing out #copy multiple times?

```
#copy{margin-top:500px;}

#copy a:link, #copy a:visited, #copy a:hover, #copy a:active
{color:gray; text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not altering the styles on the different conditions of a, you could just specify:

```
#copy a {color: gray; text-decoration: none}
```

You may need to specify visited too so:

```
#copy a, #copy:visited {....
```

Or add `!important;` after each style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you could do:

```
#copy:link, #copy:visited, #copy:hover, #copy:active
{color:gray; text-decoration:none;}
```

Also, you should use classes instead of IDs because IDs are only allowed to be used once on one page.

```
.copy:link, .copy:visited, .copy:hover, .copy:active
{color:gray; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: #copy stands for copyright notice in the footer, so I think ID is correct here, no?

Comment: It is correct. However, it is best practice to use classes whenever you can. Ask yourself: "In the future, is there a possibility that this might be used more than once on a page?". If the answer works for you, please up-vote the answer and mark it as correct.